# Reevaluate CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus in running app after app location settings change

Tags: swift, closures, alert, cllocationmanager

Thanks to Thomas's advice below I've modified my code from the original request.  I'm wondering if I'm trying to do something impossible or, if not, how I could accomplish this.

If the user hasn't authorized location services, I am prompting them via an alert with an "Open Settings" button to change the app's location settings.  This works.  But upon return from settings to app, I'd like to recognize if the change was made and activate location services.  Can this be done?  The closure below successfully gets the user to the app's settings, the user can make changes, and the user can return, but the closure fires when the user presses "Open Settings", which is before settings have been changed. BTW: If there's a better way to handle nudging the user to approve an app's currently unauthorized location prefs, I'd appreciate advice.  Thanks!

```
locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization() // request authorization

let authStatus = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()

switch authStatus {
    case .denied:
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Background Location Access Disabled", message: "In order to show the location weather forecast, please open this app's settings and set location access to 'While Using'.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Open Settings", style: .`default`, handler: { action in
            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                let settingsURL = URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!
                UIApplication.shared.open(settingsURL, options: [:], completionHandler: {(success) in
                    print("*** Success closure fires")
                    let newAuthStatus = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
                    switch newAuthStatus {
                    case .authorizedWhenInUse:
                        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
                    default:
                        print("Not .authorizedWhenInUse")
                    }
                })
            } else {
                if let url = NSURL(string:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString) {
                    UIApplication.shared.openURL(url as URL)
                }
            }
        }))
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    case .authorizedWhenInUse, .authorizedAlways:
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    case .restricted :
        print("App is restricted, likely via parental controls.")
    default:
        print("UH!! WHAT OTHER CASES ARE THERE? ")
    }
```

Comment: I think what you are misunderstanding is the `present` method. The completion is going to fire when the view controller is done being presented. I'm a little unclear from your description, but it sounds like you want this action to be fired after the user has selected one of the alert options, so this code should be in one of the UIAlertAction's completion handlers.

Comment: Thanks, Thomas.  This was helpful.  I was able to move my closure & have it execute when the user clicked on the "Open Settings" button. But I'm wondering if I'm asking the impossible. I'm hoping to test authorization again when the user returns to the app from the app settings via: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString.  Is it possible to somehow fire code when the user has returned from changing settings & check if we now have authorization?  Thanks again for your advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the extension code here accomplishes what I want - a simple get location, but which handles all authorization status cases: 
- .notDetermined: requestWhenInUseAuthorization
- .authorized: startUpdatingLocations
- .denied: Prompt user with an alert that uses UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString to open the app's Privacy / Location settings so they can make the change.  A return to the app with new status is picked up in didUpdateLocations so user location is captured after updating settings
- .restricted - an alert is shown prompting user to check with parent or system administrator to lift app restrictions.

Alert also shows w/error code if didFailWithError.

Just set up instance variables for locationManager & currentLocation

```
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
var currentLocation: CLLocation!
```

and in viewDidLoad set the delegate & call getLocation()

locationManager.delegate = self
getLocation()

Hopefully this is sound, but recs on better ways to do this are most welcome.  Hope it helps someone, as I struggled to find something that was in Swift 3 & comprehensive.  Thanks again, Thomas!

extension ViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

```
func getLocation() {

    let status = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()

    handleLocationAuthorizationStatus(status: status)
}

func handleLocationAuthorizationStatus(status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    switch status {
    case .notDetermined:
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    case .authorizedWhenInUse, .authorizedAlways:
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    case .denied:
        print("I'm sorry - I can't show location. User has not authorized it")
        statusDeniedAlert()
    case .restricted:
        showAlert(title: "Access to Location Services is Restricted", message: "Parental Controls or a system administrator may be limiting your access to location services. Ask them to.")
    }
}

func showAlert(title: String, message: String) {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)

    let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)

    alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

    present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func statusDeniedAlert() {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Background Location Access Disabled", message: "In order to show the location weather forecast, please open this app's settings and set location access to 'While Using'.", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Open Settings", style: .`default`, handler: { action in
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            let settingsURL = URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!
            UIApplication.shared.open(settingsURL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        } else {
            if let url = NSURL(string:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString) {
                UIApplication.shared.openURL(url as URL)
            }
        }
    }))
    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    handleLocationAuthorizationStatus(status: status)
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    if let currentLocation = locations.last {
        print("My coordinates are: \(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude), \(currentLocation.coordinate.longitude)")
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        updateUserInterface()
    }
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    showAlert(title: "Location Access Failure", message: "App could not access locations. Loation services may be unavailable or are turned off. Error code: \(error)")
}
```

}